# Celery can't connect to remote redis server

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a problem using Celery and Redis. For some reason, Celery won't connect to a remote Redis server.  I have read through the celery + redis postings here and haven't found a solution yet.

So far, I have tried the following:

1. Removed bind from `redis.conf` and restarted server
2. Double checked that Celery has the correct settings that I specified in my `celeryconfig.py` file.
3. Verified that `BROKER_TRANSPORT` is set to `'redis'`
4. Verified that my configuration file is getting loaded by using the `celery.broker_connection().as_uri()` method
5. Verified that I could connect to my redis server using `redis-cli -h w2214.area1.company.com:6379` and the `redis ping` command returns `+PONG`
6. Verified that I could connect to my redis server using `telnet w2214.area1.company.com 6379`

But I still get a connection failure 111 when I run my worker script and I'm stumped.  Here is the traceback.  I've replaced the company name in the URL's shown below to protect the privacy of the company I work for.

```
initializing celery
celery.broker_connection() = redis://w2214.area1.company.com:6379/0
BROKER_URL: redis://w2214.area1.company.com:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: redis://w2214.area1.company.com:6379/0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_worker_standalone.py", line 66, in <module>
    result = tasks.get_schema.apply_async((), queue=options.queue)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 474, in apply_async
    **options)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 250, in publish_task
    **kwargs
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 164, in publish
    routing_key, mandatory, immediate, exchange, declare)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 470, in _ensured
    interval_max)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 396, in ensure_connection
    interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 217, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 246, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 761, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 720, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 742, in establish_connection
    self._avail_channels.append(self.create_channel(self))
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 725, in create_channel
    channel = self.Channel(connection)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 365, in __init__
    self.client.info()
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 480, in info
    return self.execute_command('INFO')
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 397, in execute_command
    connection.send_command(*args)
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 306, in send_command
    self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 288, in send_packed_command
    self.connect()
  File "/nfs/site/home/rodney/projects/mos-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 235, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))

redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Finally, I'm using the following software versions:

```
amqp (1.0.13)
anyjson (0.3.3)
autoenv (1.0.0)
billiard (2.7.3.34)
celery (3.0.24)
celery-with-redis (3.0)
Cython (0.19.1)
distribute (0.7.3)
Django (1.5.1)
kombu (2.5.16)
pbr (0.5.21)
pip (1.4.1)
python-dateutil (2.2)
redis (2.8.0)
setuptools (0.9.8)
six (1.4.1)
stevedore (0.12)
virtualenv (1.10.1)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.4)
virtualenvwrapper (4.1.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

And my redis version is: `Redis server v=2.6.16`

One interesting thing I noticed, and I'm not sure it's related but the traceback displays the following error, even though I specify the remote server to use:

```
Error 111 connecting localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Thank you for your time and any help you can give me.

UPDATE: I modified the redis library `Connection` object's `__init__() (redis/connecton.py:211)` and hard-coded the host name of my redis server and everything works as it should.  So I will continue trying to determine why the Connection object isn't receiving the host name that I specify in Celery.

UPDATE #2: As requested here are my Celery settings (celeryconfig.py):

```
    BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://w2214.area1.company.com:6379/0'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://w2214.area1.company.com:6379/0'

    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Chicago'
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
    CELERYD_LOG_COLOR = False
    CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300
```

My redis.conf settings are the default with the `'bind'` statement removed.

Comment: the problem is with your settings, add them to the question :)

Comment: Added celeryconfig.py and redis conf information

Comment: Looking at the redis log helped me. As it turned out, I had the wrong permissions set on the redis.log file, and redis wouldn't boot because of it.

Answer (score -1):

If you experience this problem with local host, try installing redis-server by doing

> sudo apt install redis-server

Then try connecting again

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue, just poses a workaround or validation of the problem. The user is trying to understand and resolve why Celery wont connect to the specified server, not asking to use Redis locally.